# Unpacking .snappy.parquet file

Tags: python, pytorch, dask, parquet

I am trying to read a snappy.parquet file using dask and later on, convert it to a dask array that I will be using to train my machine learning model. One of the columns is an object (supposed to be image that needs to be unpacked) and all the rest are of float64 type. Here is a dask dataframe that I am referring to.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

train_path = ["/somefile.snappy.parquet"]
data = dd.read_parquet(train_path, engine="fastparquet", compression = "snappy")
```

[image: DaskDataFrame Structure]

I am having trouble to convert this object into a dask array. When I executed `data.compute()`, the floats show but the objects in the X_jets column do not. As a matter of fact, it even returned a None value. Been stuck in this problem for already a day and I am planning to also convert it to dask array. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
[image: Output]

There is a pytorch implementation of it using some `self.transform` execution under a class, but I just dont want to copy paste it. I want to learn something new.

```
data['X_jets'] = np.float32(data['X_jets'])
data['X_jets'] = torch.Tensor(data['X_jets'])
data['y'] = torch.Tensor(data['y'])
        
#to preprocess
data['X_jets'][data['X_jets'] < 1.e-3] = 0. # Zero-Suppression
data['X_jets'][-1,...] = 25.*data['X_jets'][-1,...]         
data['X_jets'] = data['X_jets']/100. # To standardize
```

Edit: I now made something new. I changed the `engine = "fastparquet"` to `engine = "pyarrow"`. Now, it tries to read the data but returns an Arrow memory error `ArrowMemoryError: realloc of size 34359738368 failed`. How do I get to lazy load this guy using dask? Snippet that gave the error is below:

```
# Process the data in chunks
for chunk in data.to_delayed():
    chunk.compute()
```

Comment: Re: "ArrowMemoryError: realloc of size 34359738368 failed" - sorry, I don't know what to do about that. It might be useful to show the parquet schema (via fastparquet or pyarrow) and anything about how the file was made.

Comment: @mdurant I appreciate your help in this problem. Upon looking at it, the column `X_jets` goes as 
`X_jets: list<item: list<item: list<item: double>>>
  child 0, item: list<item: list<item: double>>
      child 0, item: list<item: double>
          child 0, item: double`

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays are not a natural data type for parquet, as you can see

Answer (score 0):

If each element of a column is a complex structure such as an image, fastparquet will not be able to interpret it. It can deal with, at most, a simple list or map/dict.

You may wish to load with pyarrow within dask-dataframe, but awkward (and dask-awkward) is probably better if you are wanting to do array-style computing to them.

https://awkward-array.org/doc/main/reference/generated/ak.from_parquet.html

https://dask-awkward.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/dask_awkward.from_parquet.html

Comment: Hi @mdurant, thank you for your response. I did try the `pyarrow` engine and it loaded good. However, the `X_jets` column is an object and upon calling `data.compute()` for that specific column, it gives me an arrow memory error.